# Is it possible to call a method of an object while passing that object into a function?

Tags: java

Say I have a method `Foo createFoo()`. I need to call the method `boolean Foo.bar()` on the object returned by `Foo createFoo()`, then pass the object into a method `void baz(Foo someFoo)`. Is there a way to do this in one line?

If I didn't need to call `boolean Foo.bar()`, I could have done

```
baz(createFoo());
```

but I can't do this, because it doesn't call Foo.bar().

I also can't do this:

```
baz(createFoo().bar());
```

because that would pass into baz the boolean returned from `Foo.bar()`, not the actual Foo object.

Comment: `Foo foo = createFoo(); foo.bar(); baz(foo);` Having one instruction per line is usually better than having 3. It's easier to read, and easier to debug.

Comment: If you need to call the method you need to call the method. If you want a fluent interface then have `bar` return `this`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you need `bar` to return `boolean` you'll have to use

```
Foo foo = createFoo();
foo.bar();
baz(foo);
```

If you find yourself repeating this pattern over and over, you can of course also create a convenience method

```
void barAndBaz(Foo foo) {
    foo.bar();
    baz(foo);
}
```

and do

```
barAndBaz(createFoo());
```

Comment: Thanks. Just was curious whether this was possible since I only have around a year of Java experience.

Comment: You're welcome. I think this is a common situation. I often run into it when doing things like `Component c = new Component(...); c.setProperty(...); add(c);` when doing gui programming, or `Thread t = new Thread() { ... }; t.setDaemon(true); return t;` etc.